# How can I keep the element from running through my walls in p5?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, boundary

I made a facetracking Interaction using ml5 - posenet. Now I want the tracking Particle to stay in spezific areas. So I built a boundary. Somehow its still running through it. But it shows up in the console, that the collision is detected, and I already put sound as an event on it, so the collision itself don´t seem to be the problem.

```
 if(noseX> rect1X -rect1Width  && 
 noseX < rect1X + rect1Width &&
 noseY > rect1Y- rect1Height &&
 noseY < rect1Y + rect1Height) {
 mySound.play();

console.log('nose collided with blue');
noseXchange*= -1;
noseYchange*= -1;
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Flipping the velocity vector won't necessarily get you back in to the boundary.

Comment: You might be experiencing an effect known as [tunneling](https://ianqvist.blogspot.com/2010/10/what-is-tunneling.html).

Comment: @IvanRubinson thank you for your efford. I don´t think its tunneling, since the sound is working and my objects are rather large. I just found out, that if the face tracking is not working, the boundaries work :/ any Idea, how I can make both work?